# How to create MySQL table with sub columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a Database `Test` with this structure.

```
                          |TABLE|
                      -----------------
                     |ID|  |SONG| |LIKED BY|
                                          .
                                          .
                                          .
```

What I need is this.

```
                            |ID|  |SONG|
                                        -|LIKED BY|
                                         (LIST OF LIKERS)
                            |ID|   |SONG|
                                        - |LIKED BY|
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Use another table of `likers` with a foreign key to the songs table.

Comment: Relational databases don't have sub-columns.

Comment: @Barmar Another Table seems to be the way to go. Many Thanks.